# Changing the Certificate Thumbprint in ASP.NET Core Data Protection API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a project that's coming up on being two years old. When development of it started two years ago, I decided to use AWS SSM Parameter Store together with ASP.NET Core's Data Protection API. That has worked well so far, but I am facing the issue of the SSL certificate that is used by Data Protection is about to expire in a month and its thumbprint is hard-coded into Data Protection. I have to replace it no matter what because it is expiring, so I'm trying to figure out how to approach it...

This is how I currently configure Data Protection in the project:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationAmazonSsm(
    this IServiceCollection services) => services.TryAddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleSystemsManagement>();

public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationDataProtection(
    this IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddApplicationAmazonSsm()
            .AddDataProtection()
            .SetApplicationName("XYZ")
            .ProtectKeysWithCertificate("ABC...")
            .PersistKeysToAWSSystemsManager("data-protection",
                o => {
                    o.TierStorageMode = TierStorageMode.AdvancedUpgradeable;
                });

    return services;
}
```

The project is deployed to a staging and a production environment. Each environment has its own SSL wildcard certificate:

- Staging: `*.beta.xyz.com`.
- Production: `*.xyz.com`.

Each environment however shares the Data Protection SSL certificate: `data-protection.xyz.com`.

What I'm planning to do is to simplify the setup by letting the `data-protection.xyz.com` SSL certificate expire, and switch to using the staging and production SSL certificates for the Data Protection as well. This way I go from managing three SSL certificates to only two which I have renew forever anyway. I plan to make the thumbprint configurable by adding a new Parameter Store value for each environment that points to the staging or production SSL certificate thumbprints. Since the server restarts nightly it will see the updated parameter values when it boots up and apply them across all application instances.

I have the following questions:

- Will this have a general impact of only signing out anyone that was signed in at that time (had a valid cookie with the old certificate), or will this cause some other negative changes elsewhere in the application?
- Is there anything else I should be aware of before making the changes I plan to make?
- Should I keep the old SSL certificate on the server for a period of time after changing and it has expired?

As far as I know Data Protection should only be impacting user sign in, and if everyone is simply signed out I'm ok with that since they can just sign back in. Thanks in advance!

For additional context, this is an ASP.NET Core 5 project running on a Windows Server 2019 server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Update Follow Up

When I actually published the project to the staging server, I actually ran into a redirect loop and noticed that Data Protection was just making new keys over and over again. After a bit of investigation, I remembered that I ran into this two years ago with the original certificate, and the issue was permissions. So, in the certificate management console I gave Everyone permissions on the certificate and it all started to work as expected.

So, remember to set the correct permissions on the certificate so ASP.NET Core can actually access it. I chose to give Everyone permissions because there's seven apps that access it and I didn't feel like going through the process of adding every single one of them individually.

---

I got around to testing this out and the answer is that nothing seems to happen. To my questions:...

> Will this have a general impact of only signing out anyone that was signed in at that time (had a valid cookie with the old certificate), or will this cause some other negative changes elsewhere in the application?

It did not seem to have any negative impact, in fact it didn't even sign the user out when I changed the certificate thumbprint, rebuilt the project, and reloaded the page of an already signed in user.

> Is there anything else I should be aware of before making the changes I plan to make?

Doesn't seem like it.

> Should I keep the old SSL certificate on the server for a period of time after changing and it has expired?

I don't know, but it's not going to hurt anything if I do, so I will, then remove it eventually when the new certificates are in use for a while.